# Custom date field formatting with smarty

Tags: custom-fields, smarty, dates

I'm trying to format a custom date field using smarty to send emails. What I want is to have the day of the week included, as "Wednesday, April 18, 2018". It seems that this should work:

```
{contact.custom_105|date_format:"%A, %B %e, %Y"}
```

But the mail send hangs. Also hangs if I just use

```
{contact.custom_105|date_format}
```

I can use {contact.custom_105} to send the preformatted date "03/01/2018 3:15AM", so I know I'm working with the correct field.

How can I get this formatted as I want?

Comment: I confirm it does not work, a data custom field is returned as a string and it is not recognised by smarty as a datestamp. This is probably a bug

Comment: Hmm. There must be something else going on. I tested the exact code in my answer above with a direct Email (not in  a message template) and it returned "Thursday, March 3, 2022". Are you sure your custom field is a Date field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer. The civi field token must be captured to a Smarty variable first:

```
{capture assign=arr}{contact.custom_105}{/capture}{$arr|date_format:"%A, %B %e, %Y"}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me and still hangs. I think the problem may be that the custom field comes in as a string rather than a datestamp and I think its still a string from the capture/assign.